# Personal Project Download Website

Tags: html, css

This is my first month learning HTML and CSS, I have built a working download page for one of my Java projects and I wanted to see if there is anything to improve on my website.

The website works as I expect, but I'm unsure if I'm doing anything wrong.

Here is my code snippet, any feedback is appreciated!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  animation: transitionIn 1s;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../resources/images/background.jpeg); 
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;  /* auto, cover*/  
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* loading animation */
@keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.center p {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.img-row img {
  max-width: 60vh;
  height: auto;
}

.img-row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* top banner */
.banner {
  background-color: #ffc87c;
}

.banner__content {
  padding: 16px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner__text {
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

.banner__close {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .container, .banner {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }

  .center {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0%;
  }

  #head_text {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  #head_warning {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 2em;
  }

  .center h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: normal;
  }

  .center p {
    line-height: 20px; font-size: 1em;
  }

  .img-column img {
    max-width: 40vh;
    
  }

  .img-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project Name</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="resources/images/project_logo.png"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="banner">
        <div class="shadow">
          <div class="banner__content">
            <div class="banner__text">
              <strong>Newest Release:</strong> v1.0.1 on 4/21/21
            </div>
            <button class="banner__close" type="button">&times;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="center">
        <h1 id="head_text">Try Out Project</h1>
        <h2>
          Install Java
          <a href="https://java.com/en/download/" target="_blank">Here </a>

          <h1 id="head_warning">
            If you have Java installed, download the Project zip file
            <a
              href="resources/files/Project.zip"
              download
              style="line-height: 100px"
              >Download Project</a
            >
          </h1>
        </h2>

        <p>
          Please extract the contents of the zip file, and run the .JAR file.
          <br />
          For more information on running a JAR file, please refer
          <a
            href="https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001343.htm"
            target="_blank"
            >here.</a
          >
        </p>

        <!-- images -->
        <div class="img-row">
          <div class="img-column">
            <img
              class="shadow"
              src="resources/images/project_home.jpg"
              alt="project demo"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="img-column">
            <img
              class="shadow"
              src="resources/images/project_add_class.jpg"
              alt="project demo"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="img-column">
            <img
              class="shadow"
              src="resources/images/project_error.jpg"
              alt="project demo"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // removes banner on close
      document
        .querySelector(".banner__close")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          this.closest(".banner").remove();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too much jumps out; some comments:

- You're missing your `DOCTYPE`
- On the balance, if I were to be picky `&times;` is more style than content where you've used it. You can leave your `button` empty and do a CSS `content` that achieves the same thing.
- It seems very strange to have an `h1` embedded in an `h2`. You probably shouldn't do that.
- To be consistent with your own style, and to maintain legibility, do not break your `</a>` onto multiple lines
- Pixels as measurement units in CSS have a contorted, confusing and nonintuitive meaning. Read e.g. [this article](https://medium.com/@julienetienne/pixels-are-dead-faa87cd8c8b9). The days of browsers actually rendering one pixel as one pixel have been over for many years; so just don't write your measurements this way.

Comment: Thank you! The multi-line </a>'s are from the prettier extension. I just assumed it was a best practice. I'll definitely change it.

Comment: It's OK to have an anchor on multiple lines; just don't break the closing tag onto multiple lines.